# How to remove the transaction time out error?

Tags: core-service

I am getting Transaction time out error many time when I create a publication using core service .some time it create successfully and some time it give me following error

"com.sdltridion.contentmanager.coreservice.ICoreServiceCreateCoreServiceFaultFaultFaultMessage: The transaction has aborted.
Transaction Timeout"

what is the reason of this and how can resolve this error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Timeout errors on a database almost always point to lacking database maintenance, so first things I would look at is updating the database stats and rebuilding the indexes. Always make sure you do regular database maintenance or its performance will deteriorate over time.

Using the Core Service, your transaction timeout could also be related to a poor network connection, but I'd put my money on database maintenance if I were to guess.

Increasing the timeout on the server could be a temporary workaround, but keep in mind you won't be solving the actual problem that way.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are mentioning this as an intermittent issue, apart from what Bart has suggested, it makes sense to check if your server (web,cms,DB) are in a web farm and whether each one of them is working perfectly